# Recorrer un array json

Tags: java, json, array

En `Java`, ¿Cómo puedo recorrer esta lista para obtener la posición en la que esta el `día, mes` y la posición del `número`, por cada uno de los elementos del array?

```
[
   {
      "value":[
         [
            "Friday, December",
            56
         ],
         [
            "Friday, February",
            2886
         ],
         [
            "Friday, January",
            5287
         ],
         [
            "Monday, December",
            28
         ],
         [
            "Monday, February",
            5647
         ],
         [
            "Monday, January",
            10088
         ],
         [
            "Saturday, December",
            16
         ],
         [
            "Saturday, February",
            2438
         ],
         [
            "Saturday, January",
            3844
         ],
         [
            "Sunday, December",
            14
         ],
         [
            "Sunday, February",
            3032
         ],
         [
            "Sunday, January",
            3571
         ],
         [
            "Thursday, December",
            72
         ],
         [
            "Thursday, February",
            10161
         ],
         [
            "Thursday, January",
            3741
         ],
         [
            "Tuesday, December",
            66
         ],
         [
            "Tuesday, February",
            15024
         ],
         [
            "Tuesday, January",
            9994
         ],
         [
            "Wednesday, December",
            148
         ],
         [
            "Wednesday, February",
            7300
         ],
         [
            "Wednesday, January",
            5396
         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: esta esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697385/4717133

Comment: Podes usar la [API Java para JSON](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/api-java-para-json-2251318-esa.html) o la libreria Gson de Google

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es que modifiques la estructura del json y lo dividas en cada atributo (día, mes, posición) así puedes acceder directamente al atributo que quieras. Si quisieras acceder a todos sería mediante un foreach

```
for (String row: json){
     dia= row.getInt("día");
     mes = row.getString("mes");
     numero = row.getString("numero");
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Un saludo